# Removing javascript and css from specific cms page in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages

I am trying to remove the css and JS for a specific CMS page but none of the JS or css are being removed.
Here is the code that i am using to remove the css and JS

```
<layout>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/prototype.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ccard.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/validation.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/builder.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/effects.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/controls.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/slider.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/js.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/form.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/menu.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/translate.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/translate.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js_css</type><name>ves/jquery/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js_css</type><name>ves/jquery/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/font-awesome.min.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap/bootstrap-tiny.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom_theme.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/animate.css</name><params/></action>
    </reference>
</layout>
```

This code is written in layout update xml under Design tab
I am attaching image for reference.
[image]

tab

but none of the JS is CSS is being removed. I tried to debug in code but my remove item is not being called for the files i am calling. So there must be some other way to do this. Please help !
Thank you

Comment: Just confirming, you have `cleared all cache` after applying these changes, correct?

Comment: yes cache is disabled already however i have tried clearing cache too it doesnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the layout tags.

```
<layout><\layout>
```

I just tested all of these and they worked as expected. I added them to the `Layout Update XML` section of the CMS page I wanted them removed from, and then cleared the Magento cache.

```
<reference name="head">
    <!-- For a JS in the js folder -->
    <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>directory/file.js</name></action>
    <!-- For a JS in the skin folder -->
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>functions.js</name></action>
    <!-- For CSS in the skin folder -->
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/local.css</name></action>
    <!-- For CSS in the js folder -->
    <action method="removeItem"><type>js_css</type><name>local.css</name></action>
</reference>
```

Credit to @Shadowbob - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19662670

Comment: Yes i also found that we dont need to use <layout> tag . I had already figured it out but couldnot update here. Thank You for the reply :)

Comment: @magento noob -  now that you say that, I notice it in your screenshot. Didn't even notice that before, glad you were able to sort it out.